# How do I specify support for two base paths in Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

We are shutting down a legacy web service that has an endpoint we need to redirect to a new web service. The legacy endpoint is at `PUT /customer/{id}/email` while the new endpoint is at `PUT /customer/{id}/email`. From what I have found elsewhere here on SO I needed to add the following to the Configure(..) method in Startup.cs:

```
    app.UsePathBase("/customers");

    var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddRewrite(@"(^customer/(.*)).+", @"customers\/$1", skipRemainingRules: true);
    app.UseRewriter(options);
```

As you can see, the root path for this service is "/customers" and we want to redirect a specific request FROM a different root path ("/customer") TO the new "/customers".  This did not work.  Is there a better way to do this?  Am I using the wrong command completely?  Note: It would be okay to map all /customer calls to their /customers equivalents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This resolved my problem.  Apparently when you put the path in the HttpPut attribute in this way it will override the path base.

```
[HttpPut("/customer/{id:guid}/email")]
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to rewrite all request which start with customer to customers. I suggest you could try below rules:

```
        app.UsePathBase("/customers");

        var options = new RewriteOptions()
            .AddRewrite(@"^customer/(.*)", @"customers/$1", true);
        app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Note: The controller name is "CustomerController" but we use app.UsePathBase("/customers").

```
namespace MyCompany.Customers.Customers
{
    [Authorize]
    [Route("")]
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomerController : ControllerBase
    {
        //  some code here...

        [HttpPost("email")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status202Accepted)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmail([FromBody] UpdateEmail.Command command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            await this.mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);

            return this.Accepted();
        }

        [Route("{id:guid}/email")]
        [HttpPut]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateEmail(Guid id, [FromBody] UpdateEmail.Command command, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            command.CustomerId = id;
            await this.mediator.Send(command, cancellationToken);

            return this.Accepted();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, any requests to "customer" should be handled by the same service that handles "customers".  From your response I gather you agree I am doing the right thing but just have the wrong regex?

Comment: I changed my regex to match your suggestion but am still getting a 404 - Not Found.  Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: Could you please share your route setting for your customer and customers api?

Comment: I have updated my original statement with the route settings.

Comment: Please note that I updated your response and not the original comment.